# C# Sort 3 arrays with Bubble sort

Tags: c#, sorting, bubble-sort

I have this bubble sort algorithm that sorts "arr1".

```
static int yearAscDes(int value)`
    {
if (value == 0) 
{
            int[] arr1 = { 1930, 1931, 2016, 2014, 2012 };
            int temp1 = 0;

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < arr1.Length; i1++)
            {
                for (int j1 = 0; j1 < arr1.Length - 1; j1++)
                {
                    if (arr1[j1] < arr1[j1 + 1])
                    {
                        temp1 = arr1[j1 + 1];
                        arr1[j1 + 1] = arr1[j1];
                        arr1[j1] = temp1;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < arr1.Length; i1++)
            {

                Console.Write(arr1[i1] + " \n");
            }
            return 0;
}
```

I want to sort 3 different arrays using this algorithm which they compare with each other.

for e.g.

```
int[] arr1 = {1930, 1931, 2016, 2014, 2012};
string[] Months = {"Jan", "March", "Dec", "May", "Sept"};
int[] Num = {10, 5, 1, 3, 12};
```

If I had these arrays and I sort arr1 in ascending order, I want the result to look like this:

Result:

arr1  Months  Num

2016  Dec     1

2014  May     3

2012  Sept    12

1931  March   5

1930  Jan     10

Comment: Why not just use 1 array of `DateTime`?

Comment: Although @SamIam is very correct in saying that, if you MUST stick with this data structure, when you say `arr1[j1 + 1] = arr1[j1];` can you not also just add in there `Months[j1 + 1] = Months[j1];` and `Num[j1 + 1] = Num[j1];` as well as storing two more temp values `temp2 = Months[j1 + 1]` and `temp3 = Num[j1 + 1]`

Comment: Having a date split up into 3 arrays seems really counter intuitive to me. You could save yourself that huge sort function and go with what @SamIam is saying.

Comment: I am sure that this is an assignment,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested to make this useful for your work or side project, I'd suggest to use `DateTime`. It will hold all the things you care about and many more. You can also you `Sort()`  or `.orderBy(..)` in arrays.

---

**But** if you are interested in actual implementation of your thing, for the sake of an exercise, we must have couple of assumptions.

- All 3 arrays are of the same size
- You really only care about initial indexes of those arrays, and not actually sorting each array.  This is derived from your example

So, you should use 2d array, or an array of KeyValue pairs. one will be your Year, another will hold an initial index.
Then, once you are done sorting your array of Years, you can look at the initial indexes of values of years, and grab elements of that index form array of Months and array of Days.

Another idea:
You can keep the 3 arrays as is, but when you do a `swap` of indexes of Years array, do a swap of the other two arrays. Just make sure that you only use a check condition for the swam from Years array.  That way, when Years array is sorted, you will also sort the other two arrays according to Years array indexes.
Your code:

```
if (arr1[j1] < arr1[j1 + 1])
{
    temp1 = arr1[j1 + 1];
    arr1[j1 + 1] = arr1[j1];
    arr1[j1] = temp1;
}
```

Should be someting like this

```
if (arr1[j1] < arr1[j1 + 1])
{
    temp1 = arr1[j1 + 1];
    arr1[j1 + 1] = arr1[j1];
    arr1[j1] = temp1;

    tempMonths = months[j1 + 1]; 
    months[j1 + 1] = months[j1];
    months[j1] = tempMonths;

    tempDays = days[j1 + 1]; 
    days[j1 + 1] = days[j1];
    days[j1] = tempDays;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you can get away with it, You should use just 1 array of `DateTime`

```
DateTime[] dt = {new DateTime(1930, 1, 10), new DateTime(1931, 3, 5) /*...*/};
```

---

If you for some reason can't do that because this is homework, then the next best thing would be to make your own class that has a year, a month, and a day, and include a method that does comparison for you.